# COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builderXXXXX/default.conf: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, hygieia

I'm trying to create a Hygieia api docker image based from https://github.com/Hygieia/Hygieia

So i already executed `"mvn clean install"` in hygieia-core and hygieia. I'm now trying to execute "docker build . -t hygieia-api but i'm getting this error:

> COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builderXXXXX/default.conf: no such file or directory

Can someone shed some light on why this is happening? I'm still trying to get myself into the bits and process of docker and I would appreciate any tips on this. Thank you!

Dockerfile can be found here
https://github.com/Hygieia/Hygieia/blob/master/Dockerfile

I tried some suggested troubleshoot options like restarting the docker service or running "docker pull nginx" but i am still getting this error.

```
FROM docker.io/nginx:latest

COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.templ
COPY conf-builder.sh /usr/bin/conf-builder.sh
COPY html /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN chown nginx:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD conf-builder.sh &&\
  nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

Comment: That error message means that `default.conf` isn't in the same directory as the `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 0):

For the first, run like that:

```
docker build -t someimage .
```

Second, your default.conf must be in the same dirctory as dockerfile.

Third, remove all whitespaces from the last string of your dockerfile